# Plain Java vs JADE framework in terms of multi-agent development

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

If the task is to build a multi-agent system (for example, a benchmark book-auction system) and there are two options:

- Build it using plain Java, where each agent is a thread + make use of native Java features
- Using JADE Java framework.

What are pros and/or cons of using each of these approaches?

Comment: what is the purpose of the system? if it is educational you can try both and writhe the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 1):

A pro will be that Jade is a multi-agent system, and follows the FIPA rules, which are a protocol that allow to comunicate different agents

Answer (score 0):

One of the main advantages in my applications is the use of the DF (directory facilitator) which acts as a yellow pages agent. Therefore no agent needs to know the current state of the system it can query which agents are available and what services they supply from the df.

Also the ACLmessaging system makes inter-agent communication easy.

Thirdly and most important, don't go reinvent the wheel.

Cons are that JADE is not that easy to learn. Also there's alot of overhead in deploying even a simple project.